# Re-Render all values from DB or add to displayed the new one (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render, use-effect, use-state

I have displayed values from `Firebase` and when user is adding new value I want to `re-render` all display values (or add just new).

```
const addProfile = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newProfile = {
            x: x,
            y: y
        }

        await profile.add({ newProfile })

        displayProfileList();
}

const displayProfileList = async () => {
    await profile.get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {                    
                    const profiles = [];
                    querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const nProfile = {doc: doc.data() }
                        profiles.push(nProfile);
                    }
                    );
                    setAllProfile([...allProfile, ...profiles]);
                })
 }

 useEffect(() => {
        displayProfileList();
    }, []);
```

But to actual list is adding `again all values` from DB- So how can I first clear displayed data? or add to currently displayed data only new value?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is by not calling displayProfileList() from inside addProfile method. Rather, after the firebase update is done, just call setAllProfile([...allProfile, newProfile]). This will update the list with just the new profile and render it again.

```js
const addProfile = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newProfile = {
            x: x,
            y: y
        }

        await profile.add({ newProfile })
        setAllProfile([...allProfile, newProfile]);
    
}

const displayProfileList = async () => {
    await profile.get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {                    
                    const profiles = [];
                    querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const nProfile = {doc: doc.data() }
                        profiles.push(nProfile);
                    }
                    );
                    setAllProfile([...allProfile, ...profiles]);
                })
 }

 useEffect(() => {
        displayProfileList();
    }, []);
```